# Generating two or more output files with one compilation round

Tags: c++, visual-studio

I am currently developing with MS Visual Studio 2013 in C++. For my project, I have to create several different executables based on one shared source code. But for each executable I have to change the source code a bit (changing some variables and commands), and I have to rename them to make sure that I do not confuse them with each other. So, my question is: Is it possible, and if yes, how, to create two or more output executables with Visual Studio, each named differently (Exec1.exe, Exec2.exe etc.) and each with a little different source code?
Thank you!

Comment: Maybe you can put your "shared" code in the DLL (library) and call it from different EXEs included only code to be change?

Comment: This is already what I did, but then I still need several different executables because each executable is slightly different compared to the others (other commands called from the DLL). My question was how to create these executables in one compilation pass, not in many.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have the set of sources and you want to create AAAA.exe and BBBB.exe out of them, with some minor differences in the sources. In C++ normally it is done with using pre-processor. Parts in the code specific to AAAA and BBBB should be enclosed like in

```
#ifdef AAAA
 ...
#endif
```

Then you need to create two build configurations. By default VS creates Debug and Release, but you may have as many of them as needed. Create build configs AAAA and BBBB. You can specify the executable name in project properties and it will be specific to a config. And most importantly you need to set in project properties/pre-processor the definitions - AAAA for the AAAA config etc. Then if you build all configurations all needed executables will be created automatically.

Comment: Looks like a possible solution, I am going to try this!